# how to capture data going for soundcard

Tags: android, soundcard

I want to capture soundcard data.Means whatever playing on phone.It may be alert sounds,sound from sound etc,whatever sound is coming from device.I want to capture sound with android framework classes only.I dont want any native programming.Is it possible?If other tools are available plz provide me details.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is in speakerphone mode, you can record via the microphone and it will pick up whatever the device is playing, along with any other ambient sounds. Use `AudioRecord` or `MediaRecorder` as you see fit.

If the device is not in speakerphone mode, you have no means of intercepting the audio output of other applications.

Comment: From a security and privacy point of view it seems entirely correct that one should not be able to do that.

Comment: any method after getting root permissions?

Comment: @WSS: Probably, but I am unfamiliar with the details.